# Can I use ,,What's here?" functionality with Leaflet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, leaflet

I am developing a Rails app. I use Leaflet to show some maps and to mark some of my data on them. I could use a GoogleMaps-like functionality of ,,What's here?" (you click on a map and get the coordinates?)
If not with Leaflet, is there another library that could make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make your map listen to click events and open a popup ...

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    var html = 'hello from ' + e.latlng.lat + ',' +  e.latlng.lng;
    map.openPopup(html, e.latlng);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/3pt3h9pt/)